# printing formated set list of values

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

I am comparing two lists using *set.difference* I want each value that is not in the list a that is in list b to be printed on its own line, however, the set is not letting me. code and output are below.

```
import pprint

a = [1,2,3,5,6,8,9,10]
b = [13,452,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
c = []
difference = set(b).difference(a)
c.append(difference)
#print c
for item in c:
    pprint.pprint (str(item))
```

The **output** I am getting is this:

```
'set([4, 7, 11, 13, 452])'
>>>
```

The **output** I would like would be this:

```
>>>
4
7
11
13
452
>>>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have made a mistake, you're appending `difference` (a list) to `c` (also a list). Therefore when you're looping through `c` which contains a list, you're printing out that *entire* list. And not the *individual* values of that list.

In my example below you're assigning the difference to `c` directly, so `c` does not *contain* a list with your values but `c` *is* the list with your values.

```
import pprint

a = [1,2,3,5,6,8,9,10]
b = [13,452,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
c = set(b).difference(a)

for item in c:
    pprint.pprint (str(item))
```

Comment: yup this is correct it works how I want, thank you sir.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**

Didn't notice this question is tagged with Python 2.7. I'll leave it for future googlers. However, this answer can be used in later versions of Python 2.7 by using
`from __future__ import print_function`

---

By doing `c.append(difference)` you are creating a list that contains the entire `difference` set.

This should do the trick:

```
difference = set(b).difference(a)
for num in difference:
    print(num)
```

Or a single-liner by using `*` expansion:

```
print(*difference , sep='\n')
```

Comment: does set only work with intergers? it fails saying unhashable unless I convert to string (--- str()

Comment: @NULL.Dude sets work with every object that is hashable (integers, strings, tuples or any thing else that implements `__hash__` and [hopefully] `__eq__`)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this like this:

```
difference = set(b).difference(a)
c.append(difference)
for item in c:
    print(*item, sep='\n')
```

but the `c` is redundant in your code because it just appends a set into a list that has one item so, you can remove with and just do this:

```
difference = set(b).difference(a)
print(*difference, sep='\n')
```